# Custom post type URL with hierarchical taxonomy is returning 'page not found'

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom post type and a hierarchical taxonomy set up to have the URL structure contain the taxonomy and the post slug like this:

```
https://dev.example.com/site1/products/crafts/jewellery/lapis-lazuli-necklace/
```

where /products/ is the post type,
/crafts/jewellery/ is the hierarchical taxonomy and
/lapis-lazuli-necklace/ is the post name

The above URL is returning **page not found** (`404.php`).

This page `https://dev.example.com/site1/products/` is also returning **page not found** (`404.php`).

However, these taxonomy pages are correctly returning the correct archive pages (`archive.php`):
https://dev.example.com/site1/products/crafts/
https://dev.example.com/site1/products/crafts/jewellery/

The custom post type slug is registered as 'products' and rewritten as 'products/%product_categories%'.
The taxonomy slug is registered as 'product_categories' and rewritten as 'products'.
Then in the `functions.php`, permalink for a product URL is rewritten by adding full product categories:

```
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'products' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_categories' );
        
        if( $terms ) {
            return str_replace( '%product_categories%' , $terms[0]->slug.'/'.$terms[1]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_course_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

My custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    register_post_type( 'products', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Products',
        'singular_name' => 'Product',
        'menu_name' => 'Products',
        'all_items' => 'All Products',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
        'view_item' => 'View Product',
        'view_items' => 'View Products',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
        'new_item' => 'New Product',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Product:',
        'search_items' => 'Search Products',
        'not_found' => 'No products found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No products found in Trash',
        'archives' => 'Product Archives',
        'attributes' => 'Product Attributes',
        'insert_into_item' => 'Insert into product',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this product',
        'filter_items_list' => 'Filter products list',
        'filter_by_date' => 'Filter products by date',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Products list navigation',
        'items_list' => 'Products list',
        'item_published' => 'Product published.',
        'item_published_privately' => 'Product published privately.',
        'item_reverted_to_draft' => 'Product reverted to draft.',
        'item_scheduled' => 'Product scheduled.',
        'item_updated' => 'Product updated.',
        'item_link' => 'Product Link',
        'item_link_description' => 'A link to a product.',
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-edit-page',
    'supports' => array(
        0 => 'title',
        1 => 'editor',
        2 => 'revisions',
        3 => 'page-attributes',
        4 => 'thumbnail',
    ),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'products/%product_categories%',
        'with_front' => false,
    ),
    'delete_with_user' => false,
) );
} );
```

My taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    register_taxonomy( 'product_categories', array(
    0 => 'products',
), array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Product Categories',
        'singular_name' => 'Product Category',
        'menu_name' => 'Product Categories',
        'all_items' => 'All Product Categories',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Product Category',
        'view_item' => 'View Product Category',
        'update_item' => 'Update Product Category',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product Category',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Product Category Name',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Product Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Product Category:',
        'search_items' => 'Search Product Categories',
        'not_found' => 'No product categories found',
        'no_terms' => 'No product categories',
        'filter_by_item' => 'Filter by product category',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Product Categories list navigation',
        'items_list' => 'Product Categories list',
        'back_to_items' => '← Go to product categories',
        'item_link' => 'Product Category Link',
        'item_link_description' => 'A link to a product category',
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'meta_box_cb' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'products',
        'with_front' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    ),
) );
} );
```

My permalink structure looks like this:

```
https://dev.example.com/site1/blog/%postname%/
```

I created the CPT and taxonomy using the ACF Pro plugin.

I tried different permalinks such as:

```
https://dev.example.com/site1/%postname%/
https://dev.example.com/site1/products/%postname%/
https://dev.example.com/site1/products/%product_categories%/%postname%/
```

and re-saving permalink page.

Changed themes but still the same issue.

I also tried `add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );` but didn't help.

The URL structure is correctly being re-written by the code in `functions.php` but is giving me the 404 error.

I have the following template php files:

```
index.php
archive.php
single.php
page.php
archive-products.php
single-products.php
page-products.php
404.php
etc...
```

My site is a dev site with minimal plugins. I also tried disabling all the plugins except for ACF Pro.

My expected outcome is to have the following CPT page and the product page to return correct pages:
https://dev.example.com/site1/products/
https://dev.example.com/site1/products/crafts/jewellery/lapis-lazuli-necklace/